# Mover un archivo usando Shell en linux U obtener el path+filename de un archivo encontrado

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

tengo el siguiente código:

```
#!bin/bash

#Path del archivo .config
. /home/$USER/Documentos/source.config

counter=0

#Busqueda de directorios con archivos .zip
while [ $counter -le 0 ]
do
    if find $dirGeneral -iname "*.zip" -exec -quit;
     then
        #Proceso cuando encuentro archivo .zip

    else
        echo "the file does not exist!"
fi
   counter=$(( $counter +1 ))
done
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando se encuentre el archivo (La primera coincidencia .zip) se guarde la ruta y el nombre del archivo encontrado en una variable o mover inmediatamente el archivo encontrado a otra ruta.

```
if find $dirGeneral -iname "*.zip" -exec -quit;
```

No pude encontrar mucha información al respecto, (Más bien no conozco los terminos correctos para buscar y hacerlo por mi mismo.)

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? ¿No sería mejor iterar sobre el resultado de `find` en lugar de invocarlo constantemente?

Comment: @fedorqui Hola gracias por responder, efectivamente es mejor iterar sobre el resultado de find... muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes varias cositas que se pueden mejorar aquí. Primero, estás lanzando el `find`, la parte más lenta de tu script, muchas veces cuando solo te hace falta una. Además, no has puesto tus variables en comillas, cosa que hará que tu script no funcione correctamente si los nombres de tus ficheros contienen espacios, tabs, líneas nuevas (sí, puede haberlas en el nombre del fichero), o caracteres de glob (`*`, `?` etc).

Básicamente, si solo quieres encontrar un fichero, no te hace falta ningun bucle:

```
fichero=$(find "$dirGeneral" -iname "*.zip" | head -n1)
```

O, para que funcione con nombres raros:

```
fichero=$(find . -iname "*.zip" -print0 | head -zn1)
```

Y ya está. Entonces, tu script sería:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /home/"$USER"/Documentos/source.config

fichero=$(find . -iname "*.zip" -print0 | head -zn1)
mv "$fichero" /otro/directorio
```

Comment: Hola, muy útil el comentario, abajo coloqué lo que al final me resultó... Me gustaría conocer tu opinión de ese código... Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: @BrayanLopez Si esta es la respuesta con la solucion. Recomiendo que la marques como la mejor.

Answer (score 1):

al final con bastante investigación pude realizar lo que necesitaba... No creo que sea la solución más efectiva pero funciona.

```
#!bin/bash

#Path del archivo .config
. /home/$USER/Documentos/source.config

counter=0

if [ "$(ls -A $dirTrabajo)" ]; then
        echo "Existen archivos en el directorio de trabajo"
else
    #Busqueda de los archivos con extensión .zip en el directorio general
    find $dirGeneral -name '*.zip' | while read line; do

        while [ $counter -le 0 ]
        do
        cd "${line%/*}/"
            if [ -f "$metadata" ]
            then
                #Mover, descomprimir archivo .zip y mover metadata.txt al directorio de trabajo
                if [ "$(ls -A $dirTrabajo)" ]; then
                        echo "OK"
                else
                urlpath="${line%/*}/"
                mv $urlpath''$metadata $dirTrabajo'/'
                mv $line $dirTrabajo'/'

                cd $dirTrabajo'/'
                unzip \*.zip
                echo "Proceso exitoso."
                fi
                counter=$(( $counter +1 ))
            else
                counter=$(( $counter +1 ))
            fi
        done
        counter=0
    done
fi
```